# Java: Rectangles Width and Height

Tags: java

When I draw a rectangle like the following

```
drawRect(0,0,39,39);
```

Is the width and height in pixels both 40? When I draw the rectangle over an image that i know is 40x40 pixels and put this rectangle right over it, it fits perfectly. So I am a bit confused because the java website says the the 3rd and 4th variable refer to width and height, but if this is the case it doesn't really refer to the real width, just the actual width-1. I feel like I am missing something or maybe making a mistake. S

Comment: Please add more context and information. What is this `Rect` function? Where does it come from and what does it do?

Comment: thinking he means on android

Comment: If I were to do drawRect(0,0,39,39). Would that be the same as Rectangle(0,0,39,39) or would it be Rectangle(0,0,40,40). I think it's jumping between those two that is confusing me. Thanks for the help guys. Sorry for not being more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be 40x40.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect(int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect%28int), int, int, int)

```
public Rect (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

Added in API level 1
Create a new rectangle with the specified coordinates. Note: no range checking is performed, so the caller must ensure that left <= right and top <= bottom.

Parameters
left    The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle
top The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle
right   The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle
bottom  The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle
```

The last 2 parameters indicate right and bottom, so therefore if you start at 0 and go to 39 that's 40 pixels.

Comment: Sorry meant to ask about the drawRect and how that relates to the Rectangle class. I'm doing collisions and need to draw a rectangle, however I need to create a rectangle as well. So I have let's say drawRect(0,0,39,39) and that creates a 40x40 rectangle for me. However I am wondering when I create the Rectangle instance. Should It be Rectangle(0,0,39,39) or Rectangle(0,0,40,40) to match the drawn rectangle. I am guessing it is the second now. Thanks

Comment: It's the second as documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29 . To be fair, it's confusing why the Java developers would choose one format for one method and a different format of parameters for the constructor of the Rectangle class.

Comment: No worries :). If you think my reply answers your question, please feel free to click the checkmark below it to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing two classes.

- The Java `java.awt.Rectangle` class has a constructor with parameters as you describe: `Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`.
- The Android `android.graphics.Rect` class has a constructor that takes different parameters: `Rect (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`.

The `Rect` is NOT documented on the Java website, because it it NOT part of Java.  If you've found documentation on the Java site, it is for the `Rectangle` class ... which is different.

---

If you **incorrectly** supply the `Rect` arguments as x,y,width,height you are likely to get burned.  The javadoc for the `Rect` constructor says:

> *"Note: no range checking is performed, so the caller must ensure that left <= right and top <= bottom."*

If you don't then expect strange things to happen.

(Note that `Rect(0,0,39,39)` violates the documented constraint ...)

Comment: Sorry meant to ask about the drawRect and how that relates to the Rectangle class. I'm doing collisions and need to draw a rectangle, however I need to create a rectangle as well. So I have let's say drawRect(0,0,39,39) and that creates a 40x40 rectangle for me. However I am wondering when I create the Rectangle instance. Should It be Rectangle(0,0,39,39) or Rectangle(0,0,40,40) to match the drawn rectangle. I am guessing it is the second now. Thanks

Comment: Stop guessing.  It is a bad programming technique.  Read the respective javadocs, and assume that what they say is correct.  That will answer your question.